# Write Coldfusion query results to a text file not working

Tags: coldfusion

```
<cfquery name="writefile" datasource="#dsn#">
    SELECT abc,def,pqr,stu,zex
    FROM mytable
</cfquery>


<cfoutput>
    <table>
        <cfloop query="writefile">
            <tr>
                <cfloop list="#ArrayToList(writefile.getColumnNames())#" index="col">
                    <cffile action="write" file="d:\test.txt"      output="#writefile[col][currentrow]#"> 

                </cfloop>
            </tr>   
        </cfloop>
    </table>

</cfoutput>
```

I am using the above code to write a text file to a location using cffile.

But the text file is not containing all the results of the query. Please guide me.

Comment: You say it doesn't contain all of the results of your query, but you don't indicate what is written out (i.e. One row, several rows, all but one, etc). Please add this detail to assist in the debugging.

Comment: its just writing 000 could be just a part of a column

Answer (score 10):

Using cffile [action="write"](http://cfdocs.org/cffile-action-write) will reset the file each time.

Use [**action="append"**](http://cfdocs.org/cffile-action-append) to add content to a file without first blanking the file.

You should also consider building the string first, then writing to the file in a single action.

For example:

```
<cfset Content = "" />
<cfloop query="writefile">
    <cfloop array=#writefile.getColumnNames()# index="col">
        <cfset Content &= ' ' & writefile[col][currentrow] />
    </cfloop>
    <cfset Content &= chr(10) />
</cfloop>

<cffile action="write" file="d:\test.txt" output="#FileContent#" />
```

*(Note: string concatenation used for simplicity - if performance matters, consider using StringBuilder and/or cfsavecontent instead.)*

Comment: Can you please give an example to build the string with all the columns? of the query

Comment: btw, instead of cffile you might also prefer to use `FileWrite('D:\test.txt',FileContent)`

Comment: thanks for the example the file has all the query results now, but how can i add a break and a space between the results being displayed

Comment: for example the result set is like this 103002050000073000067000001000
110116050000149000000000001000 i need a break after first 1000 occurence and a space before the 000001000. i hope it is clear

Comment: If you are using cfsavecontent to create a variable, it will pick up white spaces from your source code.  If you are using Peter's syntax, concatonate chr(32) for your spaces and chr(10) & chr(13) for your line break.

Comment: Don't use `chr(13)` because it's not needed, but if you do use it, it goes _before_ the `chr(10)` (not after).

Comment: I've updated the example - not clear if it does things as desired, but if not it should at least point in the appropriate direction.

Comment: I added this <cfset variables.CrLf = Chr(10)>,  <cfset Content &= writefile[col][currentrow] & variables.CrLf  />, but it has inserted line break after every column value like this.103002
05
00
00
073
000
067
00
00
01
000

Comment: If you want linebreaks after each row (not column) you need the concatenation outside the inner loop - see existing example for this.

Comment: thanks its working, how to insert a space after a few columns for example space after columns abc and def like this, abcdef pqrstuzex

Comment: Create a counter variable outside the loop, increment it inside each loop iteration and check if it's above relevant value - if so, add the space and reset the counter to zero.

Comment: Peter I have updated the code, it is not working yet, can you please check what is wrong with it. I made changes as per your comment.

Comment: StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a place to get people to write your code for you. If your question evolves you should either: (1) [update the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14219571/edit) with the new details, or (2) [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (including link to old one where applicable) - in this case you should do the latter. (However, you should also re-read the code you have and think through what it is doing - the problem you have is not a cryptic one.)